# Bower and devDependencies vs dependencies

Tags: bower

I ran 'yo angular' and realized afterwards that it installs 1.0.8, I uninstalled the angular components, however the original bower.json file had angular-mocks and angular-scenario under 'devDependencies' when I re-add all the 1.2.0-rc.2 components angular-mocks and angular-scenario under dependencies instead of devDependencies.

I'm curious as to how devDependencies is used and if I should bother manually fixing it or leave as is.  Is there a way to specify on the bower CLI how to mark something as a dev dependency?

After edits file:

```
{
    name: "Angular",
    version: "0.0.0",
    dependencies: {
        json3: "~3.2.4",
        jquery: "~1.9.1",
        bootstrap-sass: "~2.3.1",
        es5-shim: "~2.0.8",
        angular-mocks: "1.2.0-rc.2",
        angular-sanitize: "1.2.0-rc.2",
        angular-resource: "1.2.0-rc.2",
        angular-cookies: "1.2.0-rc.2",
        angular: "1.2.0-rc.2",
        angular-scenario: "1.2.0-rc.2"
    },
    devDependencies: { }
}
```

Before Edits:

```
{
    "name": "Angular",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "~1.0.7",
        "json3": "~3.2.4",
        "jquery": "~1.9.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "~2.3.1",
        "es5-shim": "~2.0.8",
        "angular-resource": "~1.0.7",
        "angular-cookies": "~1.0.7",
        "angular-sanitize": "~1.0.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "~1.0.7",
        "angular-scenario": "~1.0.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 287, accepted):

`devDependencies` are for the development-related scripts, e.g. unit testing, packaging scripts, documentation generation, etc.

`dependencies` are required for production use, and assumed required for dev as well.

Including `devDependencies` within `dependencies`, as you have it, won't be harmful; the module will just bundle more files (bytes) during the install - consuming more (unnecessary) resources. From a purist POV, these extra bytes could be detrimental, just depends on your perspective.

To shed some light, looking at `bower help install`, modules listed under `devDependencies` can be omitted during the module installation via `-p` or `--production`, e.g.:

```
bower install angular-latest --production
```

This is the recommended way to perform an installation for anything other than a development platform.

On the contrary, there is no way to omit modules listed under `dependencies`.

---

As of *bower@1.2.7* (see [bower latest source](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/templates/json/help.json)), `bower help` yields:

```
Usage:

    bower <command> [<args>] [<options>]

Commands:

    cache                   Manage bower cache
    help                    Display help information about Bower
    home                    Opens a package homepage into your favorite browser
    info                    Info of a particular package
    init                    Interactively create a bower.json file
    install                 Install a package locally
    link                    Symlink a package folder
    list                    List local packages
    lookup                  Look up a package URL by name
    prune                   Removes local extraneous packages
    register                Register a package
    search                  Search for a package by name
    update                  Update a local package
    uninstall               Remove a local package

Options:

    -f, --force             Makes various commands more forceful
    -j, --json              Output consumable JSON
    -l, --log-level         What level of logs to report
    -o, --offline           Do not hit the network
    -q, --quiet             Only output important information
    -s, --silent            Do not output anything, besides errors
    -V, --verbose           Makes output more verbose
    --allow-root            Allows running commands as root

See 'bower help <command>' for more information on a specific command.
```

and further, `bower help install` yields (see [latest source](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/templates/json/help-install.json)):

```
Usage:

    bower install [<options>]
    bower install <endpoint> [<endpoint> ..] [<options>]

Options:

    -F, --force-latest      Force latest version on conflict
    -h, --help              Show this help message
    -p, --production        Do not install project devDependencies
    -S, --save              Save installed packages into the project's bower.json dependencies
    -D, --save-dev          Save installed packages into the project's bower.json devDependencies

    Additionally all global options listed in 'bower help' are available

Description:

    Installs the project dependencies or a specific set of endpoints.
    Endpoints can have multiple forms:
    - <source>
    - <source>#<target>
    - <name>=<source>#<target>

    Where:
    - <source> is a package URL, physical location or registry name
    - <target> is a valid range, commit, branch, etc.
    - <name> is the name it should have locally.
```

Comment: is there a way to get bower to auto removed unneeded deps when you remove them from bower.json?

Comment: @FutuToad, I haven't tried it but a `bower update` (to get the latest version with the old deps removed) followed by a `bower prune` (deletes extraneous local packages) might do the trick.

Comment: is there maybe a way to have devDependancies install in a different folder than regular dependancies? that way, if you have no other access to a production server than FTP, you can copy over ONLY the dependancies folder to a /dist folder instead of copying over both dev dependancies and 'regular' dependancies?

Comment: @MichaelTrouw this is not possible since the directory structure is fundamental. I'd suggest performing a production installation in another directory on your development machine (or other staging environment) uploading a snapshot of that via FTP to the target.

Comment: @zamnuts nice workaround/solution. Could be automated as well (better automate on a copy of- instead of development machine)

Comment: Is there a way to exclude some dependencies in a development environment? For example, in prod, I route all errors to bugsnag rather than the console, but in dev, I want all my errors/exceptions to display in the console

Comment: @Genu, yes you can: https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer#ignore-files see SO question [Filter (include/exclude) files for Bower dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263820/filter-include-exclude-files-for-bower-dependency)

Comment: What will happen with the `imported` `required` `devDependencies` that are not bundled in production? Shouldn't I get errors : `module not found`?

Comment: @Edgar your production code should NOT depend on your `devDependencies`, and therefore is not part of your bootstrap code, logic, nor any other aspect of your application while running normally. Only if you attempt to run dev-related tasks (build scripts, test suites, etc.), you will get module not found. If you require further information, please ask a new question on SO. Lastly, consider migrating away from bower since it is pretty much deprecated: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2298