# Filter (include/exclude) files for Bower dependency

Tags: bower

I am trying to use Bower to manage client side dependencies from a Java/JSP server side application.

It works and I can access client side libraries resolved via "bower install" as described in bower.json.

However, lots of unnecessary files are added to "bower_components" as declared by the dependencies used (tests, docs, examples, etc).

Q: Can I manually specify filters to include/exclude files from each dependency I declare in bower.json?

If this is not possible, it sounds like i need to resolve "bower install"'s output outside the webapp directory and create a separate (maven/grunt) copy task to create the js lib files structure I want - sounds tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [bower-installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer) which allows you to copy only the files you want by specifying filters to include/exclude files from each dependency in bower.json