# Having Bower devdependencies inserted in HTML with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I installed AngularJS via Yeoman scaffolding. When I run

> grunt bower-install

It reflexes in the HTML only the dependencies that are in bower.json under the "dependencies" section.
How can I make it include the deps under the "devDependencies" section?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bower and devDependencies vs dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339227/bower-and-devdependencies-vs-dependencies)

Comment: You'll find everything you need to know, and more [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339227/bower-and-devdependencies-vs-dependencies

Comment: I've seen that post before asking and it didn't explained how to make Grunt install the deps when developing the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in Angular changelog, bower-install is deprecated in version 9.0.0 [see here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-1), now the bower-install task is deprecated and it should be replaced with wiredep.
Edit Gruntfile.js file with this:

```
wiredep: {
  options: {
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  },
  dev: {
    devDependencies: true,
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },
  sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
  }
},
```

And now install DevDependencies with

> grunt wiredep:dev

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I need 50 reputation to comment on the accepted answer so I will have to add here, for anyone in the future that comes across this thread, the changes in accepted answer worked for me but I had to change one other line further down in gruntfile.js

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    ...

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep:dev', <-- Changed this from plain 'wiredep'
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you scaffolded out the Yeoman generator correctly (check for errors in your log), then the dependencies should all have been installed, including those listed under "devDependencies". Failing that please delete your whole `bower_components`folder, make sure there are no syntax errors in your `bower.json` and just run

```
bower install
```

in your root directory. This will install everything.

Comment: Yeah, they are correctly installed, but not automatically included in the HTML