# Difference between `--save` and `--save-dev`

Tags: bower

What is the difference? I realise that they get put into different object properties in bower.json but I can't seem to figure out why you need two separate properties for this, why not just use one.

From the documentation:

```
-S, --save: Save installed packages into the project’s bower.json dependencies
-D, --save-dev: Save installed packages into the project’s bower.json devDependencies
```

But there is no explanation of the difference between the two.  When should I be saving in dependencies vs devDependencies?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? [Bower and devDependencies vs dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339227/bower-and-devdependencies-vs-dependencies)

Comment: @MuGiK, yep that is what I wanted, the funny thing is that when I was searching around I was using `--save vs --save-dev` instead of `dependencies vs devDependencies`.  As such I came up with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Same case than in `npm`. Packages that you use in production should go inside `dependencies` and those that do not inside `devDependencies`.

The idea is that you are able to install only `--production` or `--development` variables, depending on the environment you are deploying your code.

From another answer in this community: [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)