# Grunt flag/option single or double "-"

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

When calling a grunt task what is the difference between using a single - or double -- for a flag/option as both seem to work.

```
grunt compile --watch

grunt compile -watch
```

Also when saving a grunt task you often see `--save-dev`

I know functionally what this does, but "flag/optionwise" what is the purpose of -dev coming immediately after --save and whats actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two different questions. Your first question has nothing to do with `Grunt` or `NodeJS` and it is answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm).

The second question, I think you are talking about `npm` or `bower`.

- `--save` will add the package to the `dependencies` object.
- `--save-dev` will add the package to the `devDependencies` object.

More details about the difference and when to use each one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19341028/497828).