# After build in webpack ReactJS does't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

After `webpack` command webpack catch all files and finish build in dist folder, but react component doesn't work. I don't understand why. My configs attached:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 15 versions",
    "> 1%",
    "ie 8",
    "ie 7"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
entry: ['./app/app.js', './app/sass/app.sass'
],
output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader"]
            }),
        },
        {
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'])
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'img/[name].[ext]', // check the path
                }
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]', // check the path
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Build version'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'css/app.min.css',
        allChunks: true,
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin()
]};
```

**babel.rc**

```
{"presets":["es2015", "react"]}
```

**app file system:**

- `app/`

  - `components/`
  - `fonts/`
  - `img/`
  - `sass/`
  - `app.js`
  - `index.html`

`index.html` has a `<div>` with `id="app"` and script with `src="app.js"` in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `react` and `react-dom` to `dependencies` instead of `devDependecies` in your **`package.json`** then try to build again.

Check this answer for an explanation:
[Bower and devDependencies vs dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339227/bower-and-devdependencies-vs-dependencies/19341028#19341028)

Comment: Nothung. But i find some strange think: after build html file in "body" tag doesn't have <div id=root" />, only script tag

Comment: @Mikhail that's the default output of the plugin you are using. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

try adding a template file with `<div id="root"></div>` inside the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `react` and `react-dom` packages are `dependencies` try moving them there.
Try modifying your webpack config file to some like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/app.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: '/dist',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map',
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? undefined : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', './app/components'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.js$|\.jsx$)/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      minimize: true,
      compressor: {
        warnings: false,
      },
    })
  ],
};
```

Add other necessary rules you need to the `rules` array.
With this config though, you don't need the `.babelrc` file as everything is all in place.